# Every finite Set as non-abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

For what values of n, we can find a non abelian group.
The facts I have proved till now:
1. For n prime there exist only one group upto isomorphism which is cyclic hence abelian
2. For n = 4, there exist only two groups(upto isomorphism) and these are abelian

Comment: Your title wants rings but your question and tags are about groups.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez thanks actually I was thinking about cases and for non-abelian rings, I found there is a paper by D.B. Erickson(But sadly I have no access to it) and for groups I have no references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can continue your list as follows:

3.) For every prime $p$ there exists a non-abelian group of order $p^3$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516505/prove-that-for-each-prime-p-there-exists-a-nonabelian-group-of-order-p3).

4.) For every even $n>2$ there exists a non-abelian group of order $n$, a dihedral group.

5.) For every odd $n$ the situation is as follows: see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31553/finite-nonabelian-groups-of-odd-order).